# \global variant of \csname…\endcsname

Tags: tex-core, grouping, csname

Please consider the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracingrestores=1

\def\foo{\bar\foobar}
\def\bar{\gdef\testA{blabb}}
\def\foobar{\expandafter\gdef\csname testB\endcsname{blubb}}

\begin{document}
{\foo}

\testA
\testB

\end{document}
```

The resulting log file contains an entry `{retaining \testB=macro:->blubb}`, but no corresponding entry for `\testA`. As far as I understand TeX, this means that `\csname...\endcsname` defines the macro `\testA` as `\relax` locally, which I immediately after reassign globally as "blubb", which, in turn, adds an retaining-entry on my save_stack.

In my real-world application, i need to be able to define a potentially infinite number of individually named macros using csname-constructions, which now has lead to a stack overflow because of this. (well, maybe not infinite, but definitely more than 80000s…)

My question now is: Is there a way to initialize a `\csname…\endcsname`-construct globally to avoid them being stacked on the save-stack? Or some kind of workaround which keeps my save-stack clean?

Comment: luatex a possibility?

Comment: why are you defining so many global variables in a local context?

Comment: xmltex… in a nutshell i'm reading the information from style- and class attributes in html tables and store that information in control sequences to render them later after some calculations and processing. For each cell. Individually.... And we have books that consist only of tables…

And no, luatex is not an option: too slow for professional typesetting.

Comment: I still don't see why this should means that you need groups. Also it sounds as if you would gain a lot by using lua to do the processing.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer As I said, lua(la)tex is not an option. Unfortunately… (and neither is xelatex, pdflatex, and anything other than latex with dvi output and xmltex). Besides, everything works perfectly well within tex: calculating, processing, and rendering. It is just that the "feature" described in the OP  prevents scaling: If the tables are too long, TeX bites the dust with a "memory exceeded"-error.

Comment: xmltex, ooh, a user:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle well, it 's the quickest xml processor out there... as long as you avoid \xmlgrab for large elements, that is…

Comment: Related: [A thorough explanation of the cause of this problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/505227/23765)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Instead of making the `\csname` assignment global, you can make it even more local:

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracingrestores=1

\def\foo{\bar\foobar}
\def\bar{\gdef\testA{blabb}}
\def\foobar{\begingroup\expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\gdef\csname testB\endcsname{blubb}}

\begin{document}
{\foo}

\testA
\testB

\end{document}
```

Now the `\expandafter` is executed in a group, so the `\csname` defined `\testB` to `\relax` in a group which ends before `\gdef` starts. So `\testB` is undefined when the global definition occurs which should avoid the retaining entry.

Comment: I dont quite understand *why* this is working, but it works. Thanks.

Comment: Masterful!  +1!!

Comment: This is absolutely genius!  This allows to have a fully-expandable `\ifcsname` test without e-TeX using `\begingroup\expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\ifx\csname foo\endcsname\undefined`.  Bounty will be offered when eligible.

Comment: @HenriMenke Heiko uses this quite a bit in his packages too, but it's not really fully expandable, it leaves `\begingroup\endgroup` before the test (so you can't use it at start of a table cell without preventing `\omit` etc)

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: I got a hint from a colleague that `\ltx@LocalExpandAfter` from Oberdiek's ltxcmds.sty seems to do the same thing.

Comment: @Lupino I've attempted a (simplistic) explanation of why this works, on a follow-up question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/505196/semantic-differences-of-global-definitions-in-local-group-relating-to-save-stack/505227#505227).

Answer (score 10):

I don't know squat about (La)TeX stacks (other than `stackengine`, LOL), but if the goal is to avoid having the `\csname` inside a `\def`...

Expand the `\csname` before executing the outer `\def`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracingrestores=1

\def\foo{\bar\foobar}
\def\bar{\gdef\testA{blabb}}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\foobar\expandafter{\expandafter\gdef\csname testB\endcsname{blubb}}

\begin{document}
{\foo}

\testA
\testB

\end{document}
```

Comment: good trick, but I expect that's cheating, as the OP would probably need 80000 top level instances of that in the stated use case. (+1anyway:-)

Comment: Gaining that extra-level of depth (height?), actually helps for most of my cases, but not for all :/ Am I assuming correctly that i would need one level of `\expandafter` for each "layer" of embeded macro? That woudl be bad, because \foo could itself be embedded in another macro, or not. And since I'm using (forced to use) xmltex, i probably never will reach "real" top-level with that method… Thanks anyways for the quick reply.

Comment: @Lupino As I said, I don't profess to understand what is under TeX's hood, such as stacks.  However, if the `csname` is the issue, you would **not** need additional layers of `\expandafter`...only on the layer employing the `\csname`.  If, on the other hand, the issue is one of `\def` vs. `\gdef`, then I am not sure.  But if David thinks I am cheating, I probably am.

Comment: @Lupino The key would be if you can think of a problem case that uses no `\csname`s...

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes If i use `\def\baz{\expandafter\def\expandafter\foobar\expandafter{\expandafter\gdef\csname testB\endcsname{blubb}}}` and later `{\baz\foo}` i would need to extend the `\expandafter`s outwards to `\def\baz` to raise the csname to the same level as my call to `\testB`, otherwise i have the same problem as before…