# Semantic differences of global definitions in local group relating to save-stack entries

Tags: tex-core, grouping, csname

This is a follow-up question on [\global variant of \csname…\endcsname](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/504501/global-variant-of-csname-endcsname), which asks for a solutions to the problem explained there, but doesn't ask for an explanation.

The gist of the problem is that

```
{ \gdef\foo{...} }
```

seems to behave differently to

```
{ \expandafter\gdef\csname foo\endcsname{...} }
```

where the latter "adds an retaining-entry on [the] save_stack."

So I'd like to know:

1. Why is there a difference in behavior for those two constructs? Is this just a side-effect of the way `\csname...\endcsname` is implemented, or is this an intentional semantical difference (as far as it's possible to tell).
2. What does the `{retaining ...}` entry in the log file mentioned in the linked question mean exactly? Why would it be necessary to keep local definitions after the group has been closed?

Comment: It's not “necessary to keep local definition”; the object at the top of the stack is not popped, so it remains there. The “retaining” entry tells us exactly that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks for asking this question. I didn't quite understand the example at [the other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/504501/global-variant-of-csname-endcsname) when I read it, but this question motivated me to look at it again and I think I understand now.

Basically, what was not clear from the example is that the problem applies when we have several such `\expandafter\gdef\csname foo\endcsname{...}` constructions within the *same* group (or groups nested inside that group), i.e. the save stack grows only while within the group. The “retaining…” message is printed at the time of exiting the group (when the stack is being popped), but this message is not itself a problem; it only serves as evidence that the stack had grown earlier.

That paragraph was probably confusing, so let's understand the save stack from scratch. :-)

---

**1.** Consider this example:

```
\def\a{hello}
{
    \def\a{world}
}
```

Here, when TeX in the inner group sees `\a` being redefined (to `world`), it saves the previous value (a reference to a token list containing `hello`) onto the save stack. Then when it reaches the end of the group, it pops the stack to restore the definition of `hello`. This is the obvious reason for the save stack, and the following is the corresponding tracing output, assuming you have `\tracingrestores=2` and `\tracinggroups=2` and also `\tracingassigns=2` and that the inner group starts on line 10 (say) — also I've modified the output to remove the line break before `{into…}`:

```
{changing \a=undefined}{into \a=macro:->hello}
{entering simple group (level 1) at line 10}
{changing \a=macro:->hello}{into \a=macro:->world}
{restoring \a=macro:->hello}
{leaving simple group (level 1) entered at line 10}
```

**2.** Now consider the same example, *without* the `\def\a{hello}` at the top:

```
{
    \def\a{world}
}
```

— once again, when TeX sees `\def\a{world}` inside the group, it has to save the previous meaning of `\a`. It happened to be undefined, but we still need it to be undefined again after leaving the group, so TeX needs to put the “undefined” meaning onto the save stack. The tracing output is:

```
{entering simple group (level 1) at line 10}
{changing \a=undefined}{into \a=macro:->world}
{restoring \a=undefined}
{leaving simple group (level 1) entered at line 10}
```

**3.** Now consider a similar example:

```
{
  \let\a=\relax
  \gdef\a{world}
}
```

Here, when TeX sees the first `\let\a=\relax`, it has to save the previous meaning (“undefined”) onto the save stack, just as in the previous example. Then when it sees the `\gdef` it doesn't have to put anything onto the save stack. Finally when it reaches the end of the group and starts popping its stack (which currently contains the “undefined” meaning for `\a`), it notes that `\a` now has a global definition, so it ignores the “undefined” meaning and retains the global definition. This explains the tracing output:

```
{entering simple group (level 1) at line 10}
{changing \a=undefined}{into \a=\relax}
{globally changing \a=\relax}{into \a=macro:->world}
{retaining \a=macro:->world}
{leaving simple group (level 1) entered at line 10}
```

**4.** Finally, consider this example:

```
{
  \expandafter\gdef\csname a\endcsname{world}
}
```

This turns out to be exactly the same as the previous case. This is because when TeX sees the `\expandafter` it temporarily passes over the `\gdef` and starts acting on the next token (`\csname`) — this means acting on `\csname a\endcsname` to create the macro `\a`, with a definition of `\relax` if it wasn't already defined (this is just how `\csname` works), and only after that does it act on the (earlier temporarily passed-over) `\gdef` and redefines `\a` to the new definition that follows (`world`). Thus the tracing output is the same as the previous time:

```
{entering simple group (level 1) at line 10}
{changing \a=undefined}{into \a=\relax}
{globally changing \a=\relax}{into \a=macro:->world}
{retaining \a=macro:->world}
{leaving simple group (level 1) entered at line 10}
```

---

That's all there is to it. To answer your specific questions:

- (1) It's just a side-effect of the way `\csname … \endcsname` is implemented; namely it `\let`s the token to `\relax` first. This however is well-documented and therefore arguably part of the semantics as well (as everyone expects it).
- (2a) The `{retaining ...}` entry in the log file means (see page 301 of *The TeXbook*) that the *earlier* definition put on the save stack, namely whatever the value of the macro was before it was set to `\relax` by `\csname … \endcsname`, has been ignored because of the `\gdef` (and the global definition has been retained).
- (2b) “Why would it be necessary to keep local definitions after the group has been closed?” — It's not, and they are not kept. Instead, what you see is that *when* the group is being closed, all the definitions that were earlier saved because of local definitions made within the same group are now examined, and if there's been a global definition at any point, only now discarded. At the end of the group, the save stack will be empty (or rather, have the same size as it did when the group was entered).

---

More specifically, here's an example of the problem and solutions on [that question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/504501/global-variant-of-csname-endcsname). The asker was defining a lot of macros (essentially) inside a group, in a manner roughly equivalent to:

```
{
    \expandafter\gdef\csname A\endcsname{I'm A}
    \expandafter\gdef\csname B\endcsname{I'm B}
    \expandafter\gdef\csname C\endcsname{I'm C}
}
```

and so on. As we saw with Examples 3 and 4 above, this is equivalent to:

```
{
    \let\A=\relax \gdef\A{I'm A}
    \let\B=\relax \gdef\B{I'm B}
    \let\C=\relax \gdef\C{I'm C}
}
```

and so on. Thus each definition above puts one entry on the save stack (for the meaning before the control sequence name was `\let` to `\relax` by `\csname ... \endcsname`), and only at the end of the group are all these entries popped. So if there are too many such definitions; you'll run out of “save size”.

The [first posted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/504502/48) (by Steven B. Segletes) suggested doing the equivalent of having each `\csname … \endcsname` be executed at the topmost level (where nothing will be put on the save stack).

The [second posted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/504507/48) (by Marcel Krüger) suggested doing the equivalent of:

```
{
  \begingroup\expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\gdef\csname A\endcsname{I'm A}
  \begingroup\expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\gdef\csname B\endcsname{I'm B}
  \begingroup\expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\gdef\csname C\endcsname{I'm C}
}
```

where the definitions happen inside groups that are exited immediately, so each stack is immediately popped: the tracing output is (modulo line-breaks):

```
{entering simple group (level 1) at line 10}

{entering semi simple group (level 2) at line 11}
{changing \A=undefined}{into \A=\relax}
{restoring \A=undefined}
{leaving semi simple group (level 2) entered at line 11}
{globally changing \A=undefined}{into \A=macro:->I'm A}

{entering semi simple group (level 2) at line 12}
{changing \B=undefined}{into \B=\relax}
{restoring \B=undefined}
{leaving semi simple group (level 2) entered at line 12}
{globally changing \B=undefined}{into \B=macro:->I'm B}

{entering semi simple group (level 2) at line 13}
{changing \C=undefined}{into \C=\relax}
{restoring \C=undefined}
{leaving semi simple group (level 2) entered at line 13}
{globally changing \C=undefined}{into \C=macro:->I'm C}

{leaving simple group (level 1) entered at line 10}
```

If you don't care about expandable etc. and are only trying to understand the save stack, then the proposed solution is like:

```
{
    {\let\A=\relax} \gdef\A{I'm A}
    {\let\B=\relax} \gdef\B{I'm B}
    {\let\C=\relax} \gdef\C{I'm C}
}
```

so you can see why the save stack doesn't keep growing.

Comment: Isn't Marcel's solution more like `{{\let\A=\relax} \gdef\A{I'm A}}`?

Comment: @Lupino Good catch, fixed.