# How do I move a macro expansion outside of the current semi-group, without defining the macro globally?

Tags: expansion, grouping

I've written a macro `\measureHbox{}` which calculates the height and width of a breaking `\hbox` where the lines are separated with `\break`s:

```
\long\def\measureHbox#1{%
  \begingroup
    \def\break{\noexpand\my@cr}%
    \protected@edef\@argi{#1}%
    \@tempdima\z@%% width
    \@tempdimb\z@%% height+depth
    \long\def\mesure@line ##1\my@cr##2\@nil{%
      \if!##1!\else
        \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{##1}%
        \ifdim\wd\@tempboxa>\@tempdima\relax
          \@tempdima=\wd\@tempboxa
        \fi
        \advance\@tempdimb\ht\@tempboxa
        \advance\@tempdimb\dp\@tempboxa
        \if!##2!\else
          \mesure@line##2\@nil
        \fi
      \fi
    }%
    \expandafter\mesure@line\@argi\my@cr\@nil
    \edef\mytemp{%
      \noexpand\setDimension{Width}{\the\@tempdima}%
      \noexpand\setDimension{Height}{\the\@tempdimb}%
    }%
    \message{^^J==DEBUG>\meaning\mytemp}%
    \expandafter\mytemp
  \endgroup
}
```

The macro `\setDimension` is defined as follows:

```
\def\setDimension#1#2{\expandafter\edef\csname my#1\endcsname{#2}}
```

This all works well, except for the fact that I need to alter all macros that are used within the definition of measureHbox *locally* (e.g. `\break`) but i need the result "outside" the semi-group, e.g.:

```
\documentclass[english]{minimal}

\makeatletter
%% definition of \measureHbox here
\parindent\z@
\parskip\z@
\rightskip\@flushglue
%% definition of \setDimension here
\def\mytemp{DO NOT CHANGE ME GLOBALLY!!}
\makeatother

\setDimension{Width}{5pt}
\setDimension{Height}{5pt}

\begin{document}
{\bfseries Before group:}\par
Original width: \myWidth\par              % is: 5pt
Original height: \myHeight\par            % is: 5pt
\mytemp                                   % original definition

\vskip\baselineskip
\bgroup
  {\bfseries In group:}\par
  \measureHbox{This is a\break breaking box}\par
  Measured width: \myWidth\par            % should be: 56.6946pt
  Measured height: \myHeight\par          % should be: 15.83333pt
  \mytemp\par\vskip\baselineskip          % should print nothing inside this group
\egroup

{\bfseries After group:}\par
Original width: \myWidth\par              % should be 5pt again
Original height: \myHeight\par            % should be 5pt again
\mytemp                                   % original definition again
\end{document}
```

For the code the macro is embedded into it is important, that all macros used within this macro definition do not change globally. My naive approach was to expand the `\mytemp` macro after the `\endgroup` in the last two lines of the `\measureHbox` definition:

```
    \expandafter\mytemp
  \endgroup
```

but that doesn't work, and neither does

```
    \aftergroup\mytemp
  \endgroup
```

**My question is:**
Is there a way to "move" the expansion of `\mytemp` outside the semi-group in the definition of `\measureHbox`?

For completeness, here is the full "minimal" example glued together:

```
\documentclass[english]{minimal}

\makeatletter
\long\def\measureHbox#1{%
  Original Box:\par\vskip\baselineskip#1\par\vskip\baselineskip
  \begingroup
    \def\break{\noexpand\my@cr}%
    \protected@edef\@argi{#1}%
    \@tempdima\z@%% width
    \@tempdimb\z@%% height+depth
    \long\def\mesure@line ##1\my@cr##2\@nil{%
      \if!##1!\else
        \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{##1}%
        \ifdim\wd\@tempboxa>\@tempdima\relax
          \@tempdima=\wd\@tempboxa
        \fi
        \advance\@tempdimb\ht\@tempboxa
        \advance\@tempdimb\dp\@tempboxa
        \if!##2!\else
          \mesure@line##2\@nil
        \fi
      \fi
    }%
    \expandafter\mesure@line\@argi\my@cr\@nil
    \edef\mytemp{%
      \noexpand\setDimension{Width}{\the\@tempdima}%
      \noexpand\setDimension{Height}{\the\@tempdimb}%
    }%
    \message{^^J==DEBUG>\meaning\mytemp}%
    \expandafter\mytemp
  \endgroup
}
\parindent\z@
\parskip\z@
\rightskip\@flushglue
\def\setDimension#1#2{\expandafter\edef\csname my#1\endcsname{#2}}
\def\mytemp{DO NOT CHANGE ME GLOBALLY!!}
\makeatother

\setDimension{Width}{5pt}
\setDimension{Height}{5pt}

\begin{document}
{\bfseries Before group:}\par
Original width: \myWidth\par
Original height: \myHeight\par
\mytemp

\vskip\baselineskip
\bgroup
  {\bfseries In group:}\par
  \measureHbox{This is a\break breaking box}\par
  Measured width: \myWidth\par
  Measured height: \myHeight\par
  \mytemp\par\vskip\baselineskip
\egroup

{\bfseries After group:}\par
Original width: \myWidth\par
Original height: \myHeight\par
\mytemp
\end{document}
```

Comment: well the easy method is to assign them globally to two temp register in the group and back to the local register after the group.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have some very bad experiences with defining stuff globally inside a group; something with "TeX memory exceeded"... so i try to avoid using the `\global` keyword whenever i can ;) But yes, that works as well and in fact was what i had before i re-thought my approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\edef\mytemp{%
      \noexpand\setDimension{Width}{\the\@tempdima}%
      \noexpand\setDimension{Height}{\the\@tempdimb}%
    }%
    \message{^^J==DEBUG>\meaning\mytemp}%
    \expandafter\mytemp
  \endgroup
```

The `\expandafter` does nothing as `\endgroup` isn't expandable, but you can do

```
\edef\mytemp{\endgroup
      \noexpand\setDimension{Width}{\the\@tempdima}%
      \noexpand\setDimension{Height}{\the\@tempdimb}%
    }%
    \message{^^J==DEBUG>\meaning\mytemp}%
    \mytemp
```

so your registers get expanded inside the group but the group ends at the start of the replacement text.

or

```
\edef\mytemp{%
      \noexpand\setDimension{Width}{\the\@tempdima}%
      \noexpand\setDimension{Height}{\the\@tempdimb}%
    }%
    \message{^^J==DEBUG>\meaning\mytemp}%
    \expandafter\endgroup
\mytemp
```

so `\mytemp` is expanded before the group ends.

Comment: This does work to "raise" the temporary dimension register values `\@tempdima` and `\@tempdimb` out of the inner-most group, but not for the definition of `\mytemp` within the outer group (above the "After group:" line). Is there a way to "save" that as well?

Comment: @Lupino I assumed from the name that you didn't need the `\mytemp` macro itself saving? I can't understand the use case you mean.

Comment: you are right; I was confused by my own source code… I'll tick this answer as it did indeed answer my queston.

Comment: One follow-up question thou: I learnt in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/504501/global-variant-of-csname-endcsname?noredirect=1#comment1276654_504501 that `\expandafter X Y` doesn't simply "switch" X and Y around. So, why does the last code work? Why don't i need an `\noexpand` for the `\endgroup` if is the first thing in my `\edef\mytemp…` in the solution above that?

Comment: `\noexpand\endgroup` is the same as `\endgroup` as `\endgroup` is not expandable. For the same reason your original `\expandafter\mytemp\endgroup` is the same as `\mytemp\endgroup`  @Lupino

Comment: still don't get it… if i have `\edef\@tempa{\endgroup}` i'd naivly expect that `\endgroup` is… "called" once within the `\edef`, and another time when i "call" `\@tempa`…? Obviously, this is not the case. From the solution, I assume that the first time (within `\edef`) actualy closes the semi-group, and when I call `\@tempa`, nothing happens, since the `\endgroup` is already "gone", is that it? Does `\egroup` behave the same way?

Comment: @Lupino as you can check with `\show` or `\meaning`, `\edef\@tempa{\endgroup}` is identical to `\def\@tempa{\endgroup}` for the same reason that `\edef\@tempa{a}` is the same as `\def\@tempa{a}`  both `a` and `\endgroup` are non-expandable tokens. Yes `\egroup` is also non expandable so would be the same,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134970/discussion-between-lupino-and-david-carlisle).